# Conditional Probability with Gamma Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I have a stochastic process $X$ that is distributed according to the Gamma distribution: $X$ ~ $\Gamma(\alpha, \beta)$

I would like to compute the following : Probability = $P(X_t > 0.75 | X_{t-1} > 0.75)$
knowing that $X_t$ and $X_{t-1} $ are not independent.

I know that the cumulative distribution function of the Gamma distribution can be approximated as:

$F(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac{\gamma(\alpha, \frac{x}{\beta})}{\Gamma(\alpha)}$ where $\gamma(\alpha, \frac{x}{\beta})$ is the lower incomplete gamma function.

I am not looking for the closed form expression (since I can implement the computation using a statistical package such as $R$), but I am looking to express that probability in terms of $P(X_t > 0.75)$, $P(X_{t-1}  > 0.75)$, $\alpha$, and $\beta$.

Thank you!

Comment: $P(X_t > 0.75 | X_t-1 > 0.75)=1$

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand the solution...

Comment: If $X_t -1 > 0.75 $ then you have for sure $X_t > 0.75$

Comment: I apologize for the typo, but $t-1$ is a subscript, it is not $X_t - 1$ but rather $X_{t-1}$. I am new to Latex sorry...

Comment: okay. So X is a stochastic process then,  not an r.v

Comment: You are right, I have mis-spoke. It is a stochastic process (sequence of random variables) indeed.